# Difference between two datetime fields giving negative values

Tags: formula-field

I am using the below formula to calculate hours between two datetime fields.But total is coming as -16. What is the problem happening.

```
Start_Date__c = 30/07/2018 06:59
End_Date__c = 30/07/2018 14:29

Total = -16

    ROUND( 24 * ( 
    ( 5 * FLOOR(( DATEVALUE( End_Date__c ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) + 
    MIN(5, 
    MOD(DATEVALUE( End_Date__c )- DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7) + 
    MIN( 1, ( MOD( End_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 07:00:00' ), 1 ) ) ) 
    ) 
    ) 
    - 
    ( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( Start_Date__c ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) + 
    MIN( 5, 
    MOD( DATEVALUE( Start_Date__c ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7 ) + 
    MIN( 1,( MOD( Start_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 07:00:00' ), 1) ) ) 
    ) 
    ) 
    ), 
    0 )
```

Comment: Hi. I have copy pasted your formula snippet and tried it out. I got the Total difference as: `8.00` hours(which is expected). The only thing you might need to verify at your end is: Formula field `Total` is of **Number** type. This is just my assumption. Not sure if that's the cause of your problem. BTW, your formula looks good. You could wait for someone else response too.

Comment: And yes, if you have your End Date prior to your Start Date, you would get the negative value.

Comment: No my END_Date is grreater than start_date__c .. Not sure why

Comment: What I have tried:  Start Date(DateTime field), End Date(DateTime field), Total( Formula field, return type: Number). Copy pasted your formula snippet, and its working as expected.